# Acceder a carpeta con archivos pdf y recorrerlos en angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un proyecto en angular el cual debe mostrar los certificados de la empresa recuperando el archivo con su cédula, estos archivos estan en la ruta

```
assets/Certificados
```

con un nombre especifico

```
cedula_nombre_fecha.pdf
```

este proyecto no tiene una base de datos ni un backend como tal, quisiera saber si existe una forma de acceder a esta carpeta y recorrerla y poder acceder a su nombre y regresar el certificado.

Soy capaz de acceder a ella si tengo el nombre exacto pero debido a que son documentos diferentes solo puedo darle la cédula y que me recupere todos los archivos que comiencen con esa cédula, les agradezco mucho si me pueden ayudar con este tema.

```
this.http.get(`assets/Certificados/${this.documento}__${this.modulo}.pdf`, {responseType: 'blob'})
  .toPromise().then((data) => {
    this.validarExistenciaPDF = true;
  }).catch(() => {
    this.validarExistenciaPDF = false;
  });
```

Comment: ya intentaste interpolando cadenas con el backtick?

Comment: Si claro si no que la funcion que tengo me exige el nombre completo de lo contrario se rompe

Comment: this.http.get(`assets/Certificados/${this.documento}__${this.modulo}.pdf`, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .toPromise().then((data) => {
        this.validarExistenciaPDF = true;
      }).catch(() => {
        this.validarExistenciaPDF = false;
      });

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta y agregarle ese código por favor, acá no se lee tan bien

Comment: y yo necesito una forma que no me exiga el nombre completo si no solo la cedula y ahi si recorrer

Comment: si no puedes o no le hallas dinos acá para agregarlo

Comment: ya edite la pregunta con el codigo

Comment: y ¿A la variable `documento` cómo le das valor? tal vez ese sea el momento en que puedes mandarle el nombre ya descompuesto asumiendo que documento es de tipo cadena

Comment: 'documento' se recibe al momento del cliente ingresar la cedula para buscar sus certificados y el modulo lo tomo de un array que tenemos ya especificado, a si encuentro el nombre fijo, el problema es que el archivo ya tiene la fecha es decir "cedula_modulo_fecha" y la fecha la debo obtener del documento

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo de como llega por primera vez el nombre del archivo?, Entiendo por lo que dices que el nombre llega directamente desde un formulario sin verificar que cumpla con alguna forma especial de nombrarlo.

Comment: El cliente solo digita su cedula yo accedo al archivo simplemente con su ruta exacta `assets/Certificados/${this.documento}__${this.modulo}.pdf` y ya teniendo una fecha no puedo.

Comment: mas o menos yo necesito un metodo como el file de java, para recorrer la carpeta, puede que a si solucione

Comment: Y ya probaste a hacerle `split('-')` ?

Comment: el problema es que yo necesito acceder a los nombres de los archivos es decir la carpeta donde estan los pdf para poder hacerle `split()`

Comment: entonces nunca guardas el valor de documento en ningún lado?

Comment: no, solo debo recorrer los pdf que estan en la carpeta dependiendo la cedula que me ingresan

Comment: Estás seguro que las cédulas no se repiten o de que no te pueden subir dos archivos con la misma cédula y nombre pero en diferente fecha?

Comment: Esque es precisamente eso, tengo varios archivos pdf con la misma cedula pero de diferente modulo y fecha y tengo que mostrarlos en una tabla